# Can I open a file with `cd ~/../..` in Atom?

Tags: shell, terminal, atom-editor, atom-feed

I opened up a large project in Atom. I'd like to travel to a file that is four folders deep into the project. Normally, I will go into the sidebar and flip open folders. Is there a way to open files programmatically? I'm thinking about the ability to use `cd` in terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to open a deeply nested file, try using the [Fuzzy File Finder](https://flight-manual.atom.io/getting-started/sections/atom-basics/#platform-mac) (Cmd-T on a Mac, Ctrl-T on Windows) to type in the name of the file. If you want to see it in the tree view after opening it, use the Reveal in Tree View feature (right click on the file tab and click Reveal in Tree View, or press Cmd-I with the file open).